# How to run android apps on pc?

Tags: 2.3-gingerbread

Now i want to run android apps on my pc.I runned apps on pc by using bluestacks but i want to know any other way to run android apps on pc.Is there any alternative to this one.

Answer (score 1):

An quite easy way is to configure an android virtual machine (using virtual box or VMware). You can find   the Android ISO image here: http://www.android-x86.org/
It exists many guide on the Web to install Android on a virtual machine. (only google "Android x86 virtualbox for instance)

You can also use Genymotion (requires register) which configure a VM according to the device you specified

Comment: Andy/Andyroid  is another alternative based on VirtualBox